# crash with robovm and libgdx on iPhone 6: IDEVICE_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR

Tags: ios, iphone, android-studio, libgdx, robovm

I can not figure out how to solve this crash .
I say immediately that the images that I use in my game are lower than 4096 x 4096 , but rather are 500 x 500 px and there are a dozen at most .
After a while the game will start this event happens when an actor aggiundo the screen . the actor comes visualiazziato , and then immediately after crashes , I do not understand why. Ideas ?

robovm stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] AppLauncher failed with an exception:
[ERROR] org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: IDEVICE_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDevice.checkResult(IDevice.java:205)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDeviceConnection.receive(IDeviceConnection.java:109)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.receiveGdbPacket(AppLauncher.java:450)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.receiveGdbPacket(AppLauncher.java:432)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.pipeStdOut(AppLauncher.java:786)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launchInternal(AppLauncher.java:734)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:1052)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppLauncherProcess$1.run(AppLauncherProcess.java:67)
```

Comment: Try looking at IDeviceConnection, checkResult... that's when it crashed.

Comment: how can i look checkResult ?

Comment: By going to the function in your code that calls it most likely.